# How we create custom sigup page in phpfox?

Tags: phpfox

PHPfox providing the feature to create custom page from back-end but How  can I call register form to custom page? Please provide suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can call template files within your own pages. I wrote [a demo](https://github.com/purefan/foxadvisor/tree/master/nested-templates) module that illustrates this, using this you can include the templates that display the form to sign up.

But is there any reason why you wouldn't want to use a custom template (instead of the default one) or CSS for the changes you need?

Comment: Maybe your client requires a special sign up page, but I doubt that he requires you to use a Page instead of customizing the existing sign up, makes sense what I just said?

Comment: Main concern is like they want separate registration page and login page...so I thought better i will create custom page and will call register form on custom page....!

Comment: Please go to these links: http://demo.phpfox.com/user/register and http://demo.phpfox.com/user/login Registration and Login are already separated in a default installation.